# Prefixing plugin hooks (actions/filters) with a wrapper class or functions

Tags: plugin-development, filters, hooks, actions, coding-standards

I'm developing a rather extensive plugin which has a lot of hooks that are prefixed with the plugin namespace. I have created a wrapper class like the one below but because this plugin is geared towards developers I want it to adhere to WordPress standards (coding and documentation) as best as possible.

Are the below examples recommended? If not, is there a more "WordPress" way of doing this or should I just stick to hardcoding the prefix in every hook?

Example of basic usage for reference:

```php
add_filter( 'namespace/value', function( $value, $context ) { ... }, 10, 2 );

$value = apply_filters( 'namespace/value', $value, $context );

add_action( 'namespace/example', function( $context ) { ... } );

do_action( 'namespace/example', $context );
```

**Example 1:** Class:

```php
<?php

namespace MyPlugin\Wrappers;

class Hooks {

    private static function prefix( string $value ) {
        return 'namespace/' . $value;
    }

    public static function add_filter( string $tag, $callback, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 ) {
        add_filter( self::prefix( $tag ), $callback, $priority, $accepted_args );
    }

    public static function apply_filters( string $tag, $value, ...$args ) {
        return apply_filters( self::prefix( $tag ), $value, ...$args );
    }

    public static function add_action( string $tag, $callback, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 ) {
        add_action( self::prefix( $tag ), $callback, $priority, $accepted_args );
    }

    public static function do_action( string $tag, ...$args ) {
        do_action( self::prefix( $tag ), ...$args );
    }

}
```

Usage:

```php
use MyPlugin\Wrappers\Hooks;

Hooks::add_filter( 'value', function( $value, $context ) { ... }, 10, 2 );

$value = Hooks::apply_filters( 'value', $value, $context );

Hooks::add_action( 'example', function( $context ) { ... } );

Hooks::do_action( 'example', $context );
```

**Example 2:** A more WordPress procedural approach...

```php
function myplugin_prefix( $value ) {
    return 'namespace/' . $value;
}

function myplugin_add_filter( string $tag, $callback, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 ) {
    add_filter( myplugin_prefix( $tag ), $callback, $priority, $accepted_args );
}

function myplugin_apply_filters( string $tag, $value, ...$args ) {
    return apply_filters( myplugin_prefix( $tag ), $value, ...$args );
}

function myplugin_add_action( string $tag, $callback, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 ) {
    add_action( myplugin_prefix( $tag ), $callback, $priority, $accepted_args );
}

function myplugin_do_action( string $tag, ...$args ) {
    do_action( myplugin_prefix( $tag ), ...$args );
}
```

Usage:

```php
myplugin_add_filter( 'value', function( $value, $context ) { ... }, 10, 2 );

$value = myplugin_apply_filters( 'value', $value, $context );

myplugin_add_action( 'example', function( $context ) { ... } );

myplugin_do_action( 'example', $context );
```

Comment: If you are using PHP namespaces – as you should – you don't need a second pseudo-namespace per custom string.

Comment: @fuxia This is just an example. I am asking about the overall concept. Cheers!

Comment: I feel like you can just prefix it with something simple like your root namespace. Off the top of my head, Advanced Custom Fields does this to most their hooks. @see [acf/save_post](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/)

Comment: I would suggest keeping the full tag name in your calls to `add_filter` etc instead of using the wrapper. Obfuscating the actual hook names will make the code _less extensible_ for other developers, because they'll need to check which instance of the class is loaded and what it's prefix is instead of being able to read it right in the calls to `do_action` et al.

Comment: @LeviCole keep in mind that unlike a discussion forum, here you need to be able to mark an answer as the canonical correct answer, not just the best advice. A factual answer that concretely answers a specific question. You're running the danger here of this not being a question but rather a discussion soliciting opinions, try to adjust your question to be specific and factually answerable. Also generally a namespaced class that has only static methods is an anti-pattern and unnecessary.